# How to count characters including white space and then break onto a new line after a certain length using PHP

Tags: php

How to count characters including white space and then break after a certain length for instance how would i break a string after 25 characters onto a new line using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [chunk_split](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php)() if you don't mind cutting words in half. It treats whitespace as any other char.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately somebody's already done the work. Use [`wordwrap`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).

---

If you really want to reinvent the wheel for learning sake, here are a few pieces to get you started:

- `for (...) { }`
- [`strlen()`](http://php.net/strlen)
- `$str[$x]` to access character `x` of string `$str`
- [`%`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)
- [`.`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: but does it count white-space?

Comment: @pOp Yes, look at the examples.

Comment: Unless you are after something a lot more specific that isn't described above, wordwrap will do everything you need it to do.